# Java sorted collections

Tags: java

Does anyone know if it is possible to keep a TreeMap sorted in cases where I update one of my keys properties?

Lets suppose my key is sorted by property 'a', while b is used on equals():

```
class Key implements Comparable<Key> {
   int a;
   int b;
   // compareTo, equals end hashcode here
}
```

When key/value pairs are added, they will be sorted in a TreeMap, however how could I make sure the TreeMap will keep them sorted if I update one of these keys (property a)?

Comment: The only safe way is to remove the item, make the change and re-add it. Modifying keys or hashcodes in a data item invalidates the basic contract of consistency.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts you have a great comment - please add an answer :)

Comment: @user8035311 done, as requested :)

Comment: "sorting" by one column and checking equality by another may potentially be a big problem, because TreeMap and, say, HashMap will show different behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only safe way is to remove the item, make the change and re-add it. Modifying keys or hashcodes in a data item invalidates the basic contract of consistency.

Answer (score 2):

If you're relying on value semantics, then no. Maps in general tend to freak out if their keys are mutated. (`TreeMap` will often end up out of order, which may confound key lookups...and `HashMap` can break if `hashCode()` doesn't return a consistent value while the key is a key.) Any object used as a key ought to be immutable, or at the very least not modified.

If you want to update a key, it's better to remove the mapping and reinsert it under a new key with the values changed.